# Why does f# dot operator have such a low precedence

Tags: f#, language-design, operator-precedence

The precedence of F#'s member selection dot (.) operator as used in

```
System.Console.WriteLine("test")
```

has a lower precedence than [space] such that the following

```
ignore System.Console.WriteLine("test")
```

must be written explicitly as

```
ignore (System.Console.WriteLine("test"))
```

though this would be the intuition from the notion of juxtaposed symbols. Having used CoffeeScript, I can appreciate how intuitive precedence can serve to de-clutter code.

Are there any efforts being made to rationalize this kerfuffle, perhaps something along the lines that incorporated the "lightweight" syntax of the early years?

==============

Upon review, the culprit is not the "." operator but the invocation operator "()", as in "f()". So, given:

```
  type C() = class end
```

then the following intuitive syntax fails:

```
  printfn "%A" C()    <-- syntax error FS0597
```

and must be written thus (as prescribed by the documentation):

```
  printfn "%A" (C())    <-- OK
```

It seems intuitive that a string of symbols unbroken by white space should implicitly represents a block. In fact, the utility of juxtaposing is to create such a block.

Comment: Doesn't the `|>` operator help in most cases?

Comment: @Mau Yes it does; in this case it would be the ``<|`` (directionality is important - 'feed evaluation to the -g-function'). However, such syntax crutches should not be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a b.c` is parsed as `a (b.c)`, not `(a b).c`. So there are no efforts to rationalize this - it simply is not true.

Comment: See §4.4.2 of the [spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), _Precedence of Symbolic Operators and Pattern/Expression Constructs_. The dot operator has the third-highest precedence, surpassed only by high-precedence application of type or function arguments.

Comment: Counterexample to OP's claim: `let double x = x * 2;; double "test".Length`.

Comment: MSDN has it's precedence chart upside down (lowest to highest) :). 

Still, I was surprise something like this does not work:

ignore System.Console.WriteLine("test") ;;

and needs to be written:

ignore ( System.Console.WriteLine("test") ) ;;

Comment: @George It doesn't. `f(x)` binds stronger than `f x`, but the chain `g f x` (= `(g f) x`) needs still to be broken by either parens or a lower precedence operator as `<OP` such that a slightly less contrieved examples might read `ignore <| System.Console.ReadKey true`

Comment: @kaefer Thanks. Unfortunately, I could use a bit more elaboration. :). However, I've revised my question following some insights.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who responded.

My particular perplexity stemmed from treating `()` as an invocation operator. As an eager evaluation language, F# does not have or need such a thing. In stead, this is an **expression boundary**, as in, `(expression)`. In particular, `()` bounds the **nothing expression** which is the only value of the type, `unit`. Consequently, `()` is the stipulation of a value and not a direction to resolved the associated function (though that is the practical consequence when parameters are provided to functions due to F#'s eager evaluation.)

As a result, the following expression

```
ignore System.Console.WriteLine("test")
```

actually surfaces three distinct values,

```
ignore      System.Console.WriteLine       ("test")
```

which are interpreted according to the left-to-right precedence evaluation order or F# (which then permits partial function application and perhaps other things)

```
(  ignore     System.Console.WriteLine  )  ("test")
```

...but the result of `(ignore expr)` will be `unit`, which does not expect a parameter. Hence, syntax error (strong typing, yea!). So, an **expression boundary** is required. In particular,

```
   ignore  (  System.Console.WriteLine     ("test")  )
```

or

```
   ignore (System.Console.WriteLine "test")
```

or

```
   ignore <| System.Console.WriteLine "test"
```

or

```
   System.Console.WriteLine "test" |> ignore
```